# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (typescript module)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, npm-install

Recently I ran npm install with the following dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@skynet/api-client": "^2.8.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.5.15",
        "axios": "^1.1.3",
        "core-js": "^3.18.1",
        "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
        "single-spa-vue": "^2.1.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.6.7",
        "vcards-js": "^2.10.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.26.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.4",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
        "vuetify": "^2.6.7",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/faker": "^5.5.9",
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.0",
        "@types/vcards-js": "^2.10.2",
        "@types/vuelidate": "^0.7.15",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.32.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.32.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.14",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.19",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "faker": "^5.5.3",
        "sass": "~1.32.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "^27.1.5",
        "typescript": "~4.1.5",
        "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^2.1.4",
        "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "~3.1.2",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.5.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
    }
```

When I run the code through `npm run serve` I get a following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getObjectTypeInstantiation (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57123:44)
    at instantiateTypeWorker (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57371:28)
    at instantiateType (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57354:26)
    at instantiateList (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:56981:34)
    at instantiateTypes (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:56995:20)
    at instantiateTypeWorker (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57368:48)
    at instantiateType (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57354:26)
    at getMappedType (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57021:79)
    at C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:57150:82
    at Object.map (C:\Projects\Frontend\myApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:643:29)
```

Does this have to do something with typescript dependency versions or is it something else?
I tried to lower the version, but I still get this errors.

Comment: Yeah. I completely removed vuelidate package from dependencies and replaced the validation logic with vuetify rules.